# Prevent Jenkins from creating git tag on every successful build

Tags: git, jenkins, git-tag

I want to avoid creating a git tag on every successful build. Is there any option to only create a git tag if the build was run manually, and avoid creating tags if the build was automatic?

Answer (score 1):

New solution (I miss understood the question) :)

To test if it's a manual build, you can query the following variable:

`$BUILD_CAUSE --> MANUALTRIGGER`

Next, use the [Conditional BuildStep plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) to do something like this:

[image]

It's not perfect but it works :)

```
Strings match run condition: string 1=[MANUALTRIGGER], string 2=[MANUALTRIGGER]
Run condition [Strings match] enabling perform for step [BuilderChain]
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1606993297619177453.sh
+ git tag MY_TAG
+ git push origin --tags
To ssh://git@my_server:7999/my_repo.git
 * [new tag]         MY_TAG -> MY_TAG
```

Comment: Ya pushing same tag name in to the git remote is not success so that will effect on whole build. so build become unstabilized build.

Comment: So i am asking is it any possibility create a git tag depending upon condition

Comment: Ho OK, sorry I miss understood your question :)

Comment: No problem. is it any possible way to create a git tag depending upon condition.

Comment: I've added a new solution :)